# Using WebUSB, what's the requirement on usb device

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webusb

I am evaluate WebUSB to use browser communicate with a HID USB hardware. I am wondering if there any requirement on the usb hardware side. For example, is it require certain firmware to support WebUSB? Or Chrome can have access to any USB device? Thanks!

Comment: Since the API is still experimental I think you'll have to find the info yourself. Quick googling shows a special WinUSB driver is often/always required in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser can access any device that is unclaimed by an existing driver. This excludes HID class devices since those are handled by the generic HID class driver. There are two options for interacting with a HID class device: modify the firmware to remove the HID class designation or wait for the [WebHID API](https://github.com/nondebug/webhid/blob/master/EXPLAINER.md) to be implemented.

For more information on building a device with WebUSB in mind see [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb/) I recently published.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this WebHID API could be really useful! Do you know the timeline for WebHID API project? Thanks!

Comment: It is in the works. Follow along on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890096 for updates.